# Remove local storage when the window is closed Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, local-storage

Once the user is logged in, am maintaining user token in local storage and its is available across all the tabs and once the user close the window, I need to remove the user token from the local storage.

How can I remove local storage when the browser/window/Tab is closed?

Comment: I don't think there's a solid (good?) way to do this from JS. I'm not sure if this is a great way, BUT, on app component init, you could get the current window, store the id in a map in local storage. Then on app component destroy, remove that id. If there are no more IDs, clear it. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/getCurrent
and get the id from it's return type https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/Window

Comment: server side storage or cookies would probably better suit your needs, if you want cross session sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Found this tip somewhere a while ago. You can store your data to localStorage for a couple of seconds and add an event listener for a storage event. By doing this, you will know when any of the tabs wrote something to your localStorage and you can copy its content to the sessionStorage, then just clear the localStorage afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Got It!

Just I added the below code in app.component.ts file to remove all local storage data when the window is closed.

```
import { HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
public beforeunloadHandler($event) {
  localStorage.removeItem('UserToken');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    window.addEventListener("unload", function(event) {

    //Use any of local storage methods to remove the user.

    localStorage.removeItem('key'); // key you want to be removed.

    //OR 

    localStorage.clear();

     });

// You can also try using.

window.addEventListener("unload", function(event) { localStorage.removeItem('key'); });
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onunload

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload